# Faceted search count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to implement faceted search count in SQL. For simplicity, I'll take the data that already exists on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all. A product has a category and a category belongs to many products, so it's a one-to-many relationship. I'm interested in filtering products by category, so if there are multiple categories selected, the query will get products whose category Id can be found in the list of Id's that the user filtered by (So it's an OR operation between categories). But this is not the challenge that I'm currently facing.

The query below tries to answer the question: For every category that exists, how many products would I get if that category was among the selected categories?

```
SELECT
    cat.CategoryId,
    p.Count
FROM Categories AS cat
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ProductId) AS Count
FROM Products AS p
WHERE p.CategoryId IN @CategoryIds
OR p.CategoryId = cat.CategoryId) AS p
```

The @CategoryIds is a parameter that is going to be handled by an ORM. For a more concrete scenario, you can just replace it with the list (1, 2) (so you can consider the case in which the user wants to filter all products that have the category 1 or 2).
The issue is that the word "cat" (on the last line) is not recognised so the query just throws an error.

Is there a way to make the second table recognise the first table's alias "cat" that I want to LEFT JOIN with? Or is there a better solution to this problem that I didn't take into consideration?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For the project that I'm working on, I use SQL Server. For the example mentioned above, I think w3schools uses MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` requires predicate. Some DBMS, like MS SQL Server, supports CROSS APPLY. This query should be equivalent to following one, ready to run on every SQL Database known to me:

```
SELECT
    cat.CategoryId,
    COUNT(ProductId)
FROM Categories AS cat
LEFT JOIN Products P ON p.CategoryId=cat.CategoryId OR p.CategoryId IN [list]
GROUP BY cat.CategoryId
```

Or, if you are using SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    cat.CategoryId,
    p.Count
FROM Categories AS cat
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductId) AS Count
             FROM Products AS p
             WHERE p.CategoryId IN @CategoryIds
                OR p.CategoryId = cat.CategoryId) AS p
```

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a week now. Thank you! Just a small correction: In your second query, line 3, it should be p.Count for it to work.